# For matrices (why) is it true that $\left\Vert P^{-1}MP\right\Vert \le\left\Vert P\right\Vert ^{-1}\left\Vert M\right\Vert \left\Vert P\right\Vert ?$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

I'm assuming the answer is embarrassingly obvious, but I'm not seeing it.  In this context the linear mapping and matrix norms are treated as effectively synonymous.  The discussion pertains to real numbers.

**Is it the case in general that, given a non-singular matrix
$M$ and a conforming diagonal matrix $P$ with all diagonal components
positive, we have**

**$$
\left\Vert P^{-1}MP\right\Vert \le\left\Vert P\right\Vert ^{-1}\left\Vert M\right\Vert \left\Vert P\right\Vert ?
$$**

Notice that I have written $\left\Vert P\right\Vert ^{-1},$ and not
$\left\Vert P^{-1}\right\Vert .$

This is what I have so far: Denote by $p_{i}$ the diagonal components
of $P.$ Evidently we have

$$
\left\Vert P\right\Vert =max\left(p_{i}\right),
$$
and
$$
\left\Vert P^{-1}\right\Vert =\frac{1}{min\left(p_{i}\right)}.
$$

**Context:**
From
https://www.scribd.com/read/282634061/Advanced-Calculus-of-Several-Variables

In the proof of Theorem IV 5.4, near the end we encounter the following:

Write

- the origin-centered n-cube of radius $1$ as $\mathcal{C}_{1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n};$
- the volume function as $\mathit{v}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R};$
- the identity mapping as $I;$
- and the linear mapping and matrix norms as $\left\Vert \dots\right\Vert .$

Let there be

- a non-negligible interval $\mathcal{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ centered on $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^{n};$
- a mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which is $\mathscr{C}^{1}$-invertible
  on a neighborhood containing $\mathcal{Q};$
- a linear transformation
  $\rho:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\rho\left(\mathcal{C}_{1}\right)$
  is an origin-centered interval congruent with $\mathcal{Q};$
- a translation
  $\tau_{\mathbf{a}}\circ\rho\left(\mathcal{C}_{1}\right)=\mathcal{Q};$
- and a composite mapping $S=T\circ\tau_{\mathbf{a}}\circ\rho.$

In addition, it is given that

$$
\mathbf{y}=\tau_{\mathbf{a}}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\in\mathcal{Q}\implies\left\Vert dT_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{y}}-I\right\Vert \le\epsilon\in\left(0,1\right).
$$

So, by the chain rule and the linearity of $\rho$ we have

$$
dS_{\mathbf{0}}^{-1}\circ dS_{\mathbf{x}}=\left(dT_{\mathbf{a}}\circ\rho\right)^{-1}\circ\left(dT_{\mathbf{y}}\circ\rho\right)=\rho^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{y}}\circ\rho.
$$

Therefore

$$
\left\Vert dS_{\mathbf{0}}^{-1}\circ dS_{\mathbf{x}}-I\right\Vert \le\left\Vert \rho\right\Vert ^{-1}\left\Vert dT_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{y}}-I\right\Vert \left\Vert \rho\right\Vert .
$$

**It's the last part that I'm not following.**

The part I do (believe I) understand is

$$
dS_{\mathbf{0}}^{-1}\circ dS_{\mathbf{x}}-I=\rho^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{y}}\circ\rho-I
$$

$$
=\rho^{-1}\circ\left(dT_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1}\circ dT_{\mathbf{y}}-I\right)\circ\rho.
$$

The norms I am using:
[image]

Just for fun, this is a partial depiction of what is going on in the proof.

[image]

Comment: You should specify the norm that you are using for the matrices(operators). There are numerous norms, or should it hold for all norms. I will guess that it is the operator norm based on linear maps from a finite  k-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers into a finite  k-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: Edwards uses the definite article, so I assumed there was general acceptance of his terms.  I've added my definitions.

Comment: You won't need to lay it out all the time in the context of a textbook or such since the notation will be obvious from the earlier sections and the context. Pulling it into a general forum like this it helps to provide that background info since there are questions of all types on the site. It is clear now.

Comment: Doesn't seem true (unless I misread the question or there are some conditions I am missing). Consider $P=\text{diag}(2, 1/2)$ and $M=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $||P||=2$, $||M||=1$, so $||P||^{-1}||M|| ||P|| = 1$. But $P^{-1}MP=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 4 \\ 1/4 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which has norm $4$.

Comment: Right. $\|P^{-1}\|$ is rarely $\|P\|^{-1}$. Nick's example is one where $\|P^{-1}\| = \|P\|$, in fact. Yes, I remember catching that error in Edwards's book many, many years ago, precisely in the change of variables theorem section. You can find a correct proof, modeled on his, in my *Multivariable Mathematics*. (There is still an error or two in mine, explained in the errata linked on my homepage.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm a vagabond, so I can't carry a lot of books with me.  Is you book available in electronic form?  I would happily pay good money for it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the statement
$$
\left\Vert P^{-1}MP\right\Vert \le\left\Vert P\right\Vert ^{-1}\left\Vert M\right\Vert \left\Vert P\right\Vert
$$

actually **is** correct, but it is misleading in the current context.  It's correct because
$$
\left\Vert P^{-1}MP\right\Vert \le\left\Vert P^{-1}\left\Vert M\right\Vert  P\right\Vert=\left\Vert M\right\Vert,
$$
which my have been what Edwards actually intended.